# Janusgraph Kotlin "select" step what type is it?

Tags: kotlin, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

can't execute the below query because Kotlin can't interfere type of "select" step.

```
val query = g.V().hasLabel(VLabels.USER).fold().coalesce(
        unfold(),
        addV<Vertex>(VLabels.USER)
    ).aggregate("user").V().hasLabel(VLabels.SERVICE_SUBSCRIPTION).fold().coalesce(
        unfold<Vertex>(),
        addV<Vertex>(VLabels.SERVICE_SUBSCRIPTION).
                aggregate("subscription").
            sideEffect(addE<Edge>(ELabels.OWNS).from(select("user").unfold()).to(select("subscription").unfold()))
    ).next()
```

The question is, "select" step what type is it?

Comment: what is the error? do you have correct import?

Comment: fixed, thanks needed "select<Any,Any>" but I did "select<Map<Any,Any>>"